# counting words in a string and arrange them by quantity

Tags: c#

this is what i came up with so far, it doesnt matter that "," isnt cut from the words

im trying to find a more efficient way than creating 3 different dictionaries etc, also the words dont need to be arranged alphabetically

any ideas? sorry if my question is explained poorly im new here

```
        string sentence = "a my name is bob, my name is rob";

        string[] split = sentence.Split();
    
        var sortedAndCounted = from c in split.GroupBy(x => x).OrderBy(x => x.Key)
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      word = c.Key,                              
                                      number = split.Where(x => x.Equals(c.Key)).Count()
                                  };

        Dictionary<string, int> List = sortedAndCounted.ToDictionary(x => x.word, x1 => x1.number);

        var newList = List.OrderByDescending(x=> x.Value);
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because your question with its _["no actual problem to be solved"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)_, kinda sounds like _code improvement_ and/or _review_ and if so may be off-topic for SO.  It _may_ be better suited for another SE site but be sure to read the relevant FAQ; and/or re-wording your question as necessary before cross-posting.  [ask].  Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
string sentence = "a my name is bob, my name is rob";

string[] split = sentence.Split();

var sortedAndCounted = from c in split.GroupBy(x => x).OrderBy(x => x.Key)
                                   select new
                                   {
                                       word = c.Key,
                                       number = split.Where(x => x.Equals(c.Key)).Count()
                                   };
var List = sortedAndCounted.ToList().OrderBy(x => x.number);
```